# File List iteration in pagination way

Tags: python

I am iterating files within a directory where chances of thousands of files in each directory. Memory usage should be optimized by keeping certain predefined number of absolute file paths in memory & rest to be cached in disk file, in binary format and should be able to seek to desired record numbers.

Need an iterator like iterator class with folder path as parameter.

At the time of initializing check file existence(directory.bin). If file does not exists find all all file paths recursively with in child folders and save them into file(directory.bin)

If present, it should return given no of file paths from directory.bin

I want a program for this scenario in python, am trying to do it, but not able to get it. Any one helps is appreciates.

This is input:

Directory file_1 file_2 sub/ file_11 file_22 other/ sub/ file_111 file_222

Lets assume above is a directory with files. If i call a iterator with directory path and threshold value as parameters

On initialization , it should recursively read all absoulte filepaths and saves to a binary file. Later on calling next() it should return no of threshold filepaths from binary file. on next() second time, should return next no of threshold filepaths from same binary file.

Assumption output below

Ex: FileList(directory_path,10) it should saves all filepaths into directory_path.bin On next call should return no of file paths from directory_path.bin == first 10 filepaths in next iteration should return no of file paths from directory_path.bin == second set of 10 filepaths

Comment: You probably want `os.walk`.

Comment: "am trying to do it, but not able to get it." Please include your attempts in the question along with the issues so that specific advice can be given.

Comment: Yes correct but i need an iterator which will return limited no of files on each call of next method. by using os.walk i can store all filepaths in binary file, but when i request for certain no of files, it should return only those no of files from binary file where stored all filepaths.

Comment: Although, `os.walk` returns a list of filenames. You might have to roll your own with `os.scandir` and lazily evaluate everything in each directory.

Comment: Please add simple use cases or expected input/outputs. 

Help us help you.

Comment: This is input: 

Directory
 file_1
 file_2
 sub/
  file_11
  file_22
 other/
  sub/
   file_111
   file_222